# JavaCPP Leptonica : How to clear memory of pixClone handles

Tags: leptonica, javacpp

Until now, I've always used [pixDestroy](https://tpgit.github.io/Leptonica/pix1_8c_source.html#l00466) to clean up PIX objects in my JavaCPP/Leptonica application. However, I recently noticed a weird memory leak issue that I tracked down to a Leptonica function internally returning a pixClone result. I managed to reproduce the issue by using the following simple test:

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        String pathImg = "...";

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            PIX img   = pixRead(pathImg);
            PIX clone = pixClone(img);

            pixDestroy(clone);
            pixDestroy(img);
        }

        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
```

When the Thread.sleep is reached, the RAM memory usage in Windows task manager (not the heap size) has increased to about 1GB and is not released until the sleep ends and the test finishes.

Looking at the docs of [pixClone](https://tpgit.github.io/Leptonica/pix1_8c_source.html#l00440), we see it actually creates a handle to the existing PIX:

> Notes:
>
> 1. A "clone" is simply a handle (ptr) to an existing pix. It is implemented because (a) images can be large and hence expensive to
>      copy, and (b) extra handles to a data structure need to be made with a
>      simple policy to avoid both double frees and memory leaks. Pix are
>      reference counted. The side effect of pixClone() is an increase by 1
>      in the ref count.
> 2. The protocol to be used is: (a) Whenever you want a new handle to an existing image, call pixClone(), which just bumps a ref count. (b)
>      Always call pixDestroy() on all handles. This decrements the ref
>      count, nulls the handle, and only destroys the pix when pixDestroy()
>      has been called on all handles.

If I understand this correctly, I am indeed calling pixDestroy on all handles, so the ref count should reach zero and thus the PIX should have been destroyed. Clearly, this is not the case though. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an optimization for the common case when a function returns a pointer it receives as argument, JavaCPP also returns the same object to the JVM. This is what is happening with `pixClone()`. It simply returns the pointer that the user passes as argument, and thus both `img` and `clone` end up referencing the same object in Java.

Now, when `pixDestroy()` gets called on the first reference `img`, Leptonica helpfully resets its address to 0, but we've now lost the address, and the second call to `pixDestroy()` receives that null pointer, resulting in a noop, and a memory leak.

One easy way to avoid this issue is by creating explicitly a new `PIX` reference after each call to `pixClone()`, for example, in this case:

```
PIX clone = new PIX(pixClone(img));
```